# Filter Multilevel pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

How can I filter a pandas Groupby multilevel?

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame( {"Country" : ["Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Italy", "Italy", "Brazil"],
                    "City" : ["Sao Paulo", "Sao Paulo", "Rio de Janeiro", "Roma", "Roma", "Sao Paulo"],
                    "Vehicule" : ["Bike", "Car", "Car", "Car", "Bike", "Bike"],
                    "Value" : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6]})
group = df.groupby(by=["Country", "City", "Vehicule"]).sum().loc[:,"Value"]
print(group)
```

How can I filter just the level by the vehicule "Bike", and show me percentage of bike and cars.

Comment: What is expected output?

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to filter first, then group-by:

```
df[df.Vehicule=="Bike"].groupby(["Country", "City"]).sum()
```

Or:

```
df.groupby(["Country", "City", "Vehicule"]).sum().unstack().Value.Bike
```

The latter produces NaN for cities with none:

```
Country  City          
Brazil   Rio de Janeiro    NaN
         Sao Paulo         7.0
Italy    Roma              5.0
```

Or as a fraction:

```
x = df.groupby(["Country", "City", "Vehicule"]).sum().unstack().Value
x.Bike / x.sum(1)
```

Gives you:

```
Country  City          
Brazil   Rio de Janeiro         NaN
         Sao Paulo         0.777778
Italy    Roma              0.555556
```

Comment: Ya, but this is a bit unclear `and show me percentage of bike and cars`

Comment: I need car's value. I need to compare the values from Bike and Cars whenever a city have bike.

Comment: @wanuke: "Compare" doesn't tell us much.  Compare how?  Subtraction?  Ratio?  Qualitative/categorical/presence?  Sort?  Tell us precisely what the output is supposed to be, by editing your question.